# String to ActivityDateTime

Tags: apex, class, datetime, event

I have two strings that populated with values:
`Startdate` and `StartHour`. The `StartDate` string is populated with the date and the `StartHour` populated with the time in format `hh:mm`.

When I populate the `ActivityDateTime` field, it gives me a value in the AM.

```
ev.ActivityDateTime = DateTime.valueof(Date.parse(StartDate)+'T'+startHour+':00');
```

These are the values I'm using to populate the `ActivityDateTime`:

- startHour: `14:00`
- startDate: `9/23/2016`

So when the user picks the time `14:00` or higher in the `ActivityDateTime` field, it shows as `12:00 AM`.

How can I define AM or PM in the `Apex Class` or make automatically defined?

Comment: What if you try `valueOfGmt`? Alternatively, you could do `newInstanceGmt(Date, Time)` and split `startHour` on `':'` to create a `Time` instance.

Comment: if I use DateTime.valueofGmt(Date.parse(StartDate)+'T'+startHour+':00'); it always sets the time to 3 AM.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include explicit sample values for `startDate` and `startHour`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the `Datetime.newInstanceGmt(Date, Time)` method to be more consistent. This approach seems to work:

```
public static Datetime parse(String startDate, String startHour)
{
    List<String> hourComponents = startHour.split(':');
    return Datetime.newInstanceGmt(
        Date.parse(startDate),
        Time.newInstance(
            Integer.valueOf(hourComponents[0]),
            Integer.valueOf(hourComponents[1]),
            0, 0
        )
    );
}
```

You would then just do:

```
ev.ActivityDateTime = parse(startDate, startHour);
```

Or if it's in a separate class:

```
ev.ActivityDateTime = SomeClass.parse(startDate, startHour);
```

Comment: Thanks for help! But how i must assign pased value to the ev.ActivitydateTime?